# Segurança ao enviar e pegar dados de uma URL

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express.js

Olá,
Estou aprendendo desenvolvimento e não sei muito sobre segurança. 
Estou fazendo uma aplicação web usando `Nodejs` + `Expressjs` + `AngularJs` + `MongoDB`. Fiz da seguinte forma , os dados do MongoDB são enviados para uma URL usando o método `Post` , e depois eu "acesso" esses dados com AngularJs e mostro na tela. Gostaria de saber o quanto isso é inseguro.
Segue código:

**Primeiro criei um Schema da minha coleção do MongoDB:**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new Schema({
    nome: String,
    idade: Number,
    CPF: String,
    email: String
});

var User = mongoose.model('User' , userSchema );

module.exports = User;
```

**Depois peguei esse Schema em um arquivo e criei uma URL e enviei os dados usando método `POST`**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var User = require('../models/users');

//Se aqui for router.get os dados serão exibidos na URL localhost/api/users
//Então usei router.post
router.post('/api/users' , function(req, res, next){
  User.find(function(err, users){
    res.json(users);
 });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**Por fim , peguei os dados da URL e exibi na tela com o Angular:**

```
app.controller("RBScontroller", function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.enviar = function enviar(){

        var ApiMongo = 'http://localhost:3000/api/users';
        $scope.users = [];
        $scope.loading = true;      

        $http.post(ApiMongo).success(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $scope.users = data;
            $scope.loading = false;             

        }).error(function(msg) {      

            angular.element($(function(){alert("Fail")}));
            $scope.loading = false;
        });
    }   
});
```

Esse método deixa os dados expostos de alguma maneira?
Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os dados do usuário ficam expostos através do conceito de [API](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_de_programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_aplica%C3%A7%C3%B5es). O Express faz a consulta ao banco de dados, nesse caso o `MongoDB` através do `Moongose` e retorna isso através de uma chamada [REST](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST) com o `Express`.

Essas informações podem ser protegidas com uma autenticação, podem ser a que você preferir, tipo *Basic Authentication* ou [oAuth](http://oauth.net/). Isso protege as suas informações evitando que pessoas sem um token acessem as informações. Para isso você precisa criar um `/api/token` se for usar um oAuth. E no caso de `basic Auth` só usar a authenticação `http`.

O interessante de ser ter uma API é o acesso por outros aplicações, digamos por exemplo que no seu caso você quer desenvolver um aplicativo nativo para celular e consultar os dados do usuário, só por acessar o `/api/users`.

**TL;DR;** Sim, fica exposto e para isso você precisa implementar uma Autenticação para cada consulta aos dados.